# finding big oh for prime algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, big-o, time-complexity, primes

```
void print(int num)

{
    for(int i=2; i<sqrt(num); i++) // VS for(int i=2; i<num/2; i++)
    {
        if(num%i==0)
        {
            cout<<"not prime\n";
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    cout<<"prime\n";        
}
```

I know that these algorithms are slow for finding primes but I hope to learn about Big oh using these examples.
Im assuming that the algorithm that goes from i=2 to i

Can someone explain the running time of both of the algorithms in terms of the input num using big oh notation?

Comment: _"Im assuming that the algorithm that goes from i=2 to i"_... Yes? What are you assuming about it?

Comment: This is your third very basic question about big-o of single loops. maybe you should pick up an book or video lecture on this topic...

Comment: Actually, big-oh in general isn't very interesting, you should care about actual performance instead.  Yes, this can be *very* different.  In this case here you calculate the square root within the loop, which can be rather costly.  So any performance optimization is pointless as long as such glaring hogs are sitting there.  Well, maybe you are luck and the compiler fixes this for you, but you should not depend on that.

Comment: Maybe my eyes are playing tricks on me but.. shouldn't that for loop condition be 'i<=sqrt(num)' ?  Right now, I'm not sure it handles square numbers correctly...

Answer (score 1):

If you run this, you will actually go through the loop `sqrt(num)-2` times, i.e. for i==2 to i==sqrt(num), increasing step by 1 at a time.

Thus, in terms of size of `num`, this algorithm's running time is `O( sqrt(num) )`.

Comment: Versus the commented alternative, which is O(n). Use the square root version.

Answer (score 1):

As only constant statements are within `if`-statement, the total time complexity is actually determined by the `for`-loop.

```
for(int i=2; i<sqrt(num); i++)
```

This means it will run `sqrt(num)-2` times, so the total complexity is `O(sqrt(n))`.

And easily, you will realize if the `for`-loop changes to:

```
for(int i=2; i<num/2; i++)
```

, it will run `num/2-2` times, thus the total complexity will be `O(num)`.

Answer (score 1):

First we have to specify our task. So what we want is to find a function

```
f(N) = number_of_steps
```

when N is your num argument passed to function. From this point forward we are going to assume that every sentence that doesn't depend on the size of the input data takes a constant `C` number computational steps.

We are going to add the individual number of steps of the function.

```
f(N) = for_ + C;
```

Now how many times will be for executed? sqrt(N)-2, so:

```
f(N) = sqrt(N) -2 + C = sqrt(num) -2 + C

O( f(num)) = sqrt(num)
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated in other answers, the cost of the algorithm that iterates from 2 to sqrt(n) is O(sqrt n) and the cost of the algorithm that iterates from 2 to n/2 is O(n). However, these bounds apply for the worst case, and the worst case happens when n is prime.

In the average, both algorithms run in O(1) expected time: Half of the numbers are even, so their cost is 2*n/2. A third of the numbers are multiple of 3, so their cost is 3*n/3. A 1/4 of the numbers are multiple of 4, so their cost is 4*n/4...